# Not Able to set resource type in logs using command 'gcloud logging logs write' . Entries getting created under global resource type

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Google compute engine.
I am using the steps as shown in Google cloud documentation. My command is 
sudo gcloud logging write "logname"  "A simple entry"

The entry gets created but under the resource type as 'global'. However i want it to be created under resource name as compute engine.

I have tried setting logname as "projects/campuskudos-980/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fvm.syslog" but that didn't work out

```
sudo gcloud logging write "logname"  "A simple entry"
```

I want the logs to be created under `GCE VM Instance` resource type. So I can filter it out on stackdriver

Answer (score 0):

Currently there’s no way to specify the resource type when using gcloud logging write command. As explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#log_entries) for simplicity, this command makes several assumptions about the log entry. For instance, it always sets the resource type to global.

Right now, there are two ways to do that:

1- With the `gcloud logging write` command, use `logname` and specify something like `projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/compute.googleapis.com`. After that, using advanced filters on Stackdriver Logging as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters), you can filter logs using an advanced filter to query all entries inside ‘compute.googleapis.com’.
For e.g.:

```
logName: (“projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/compute.googleapis.com”)
```

2- Call directly to [API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write) as explained in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs#writing_log_entries) specifying resource type as `gce_instance`. 
Then that entry will appear under `GCE VM Instance` resource type on Stackdriver Logging.